# Pass whole MYSQL statement from android to PHP

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm new to PHP and using it to interact with databases through android. Rather than having the specific query/statement in the PHP code, I'd like to just be able to save it as a variable and then forward it to the PHP server. Is this possible? With my code shown below, I get an error,

```
Exception Illegal character in query at index 67: phpfilelocation.php?statement=SELECT * FROM Users

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect(loginhere);

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$statement = $_POST["'statement'"];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"'$statement");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$data = $row[0];

if($data){
echo $data;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: It's possible, but you should consider if it's a good idea. I wouldn't want to have a service/page that reads a parameter with a SQL statement and executes it in the database. From a security point of view it's a nightmare. It would be better to have the SQL statement in PHP and call the service/page just with the parameters for the query

Comment: Apart from that, your code doesn't work because the quotes are not placed correctly: `$_POST["'statement'"];` should be `$_POST["statement"];`, and `mysqli_query($con,"'$statement")` should be `mysqli_query($con,$statement)`. But again: don't do it the way you are doing it, you are not even parsing the SQL before sending it to the database. That cannot end well.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. What would be the best way to do what I want? Should I just make multiple php scripts with different types of statements or queries?

Comment: You could have just one PHP with all the queries, then pass a parameter indicating which one has to be run (along with the parameters if any)